# How to do a calculation on Python with a random operator

Tags: python, random

I am making a maths test where each question will be either adding, multiplying or subtracting randomly chosen numbers.  My operator will be chosen at random, however I cannot work out how to calculate with the operator.  My problem is here:

```
answer = input()
if answer ==(number1,operator,number2):
    print('Correct')
```

How can I make it so the operator is used in a calculation.  For example, if the random numbers were two and five, and the random operator was '+', how would I code my program so that it would end up actually doing the calculation and getting an answer, so in this case it would be:

```
answer =input()
if answer == 10:
    print('Correct')
```

Basically, how can I do a calculation to check to see if the answer is actually correct?
My full code is below.

```
import random
score = 0 #score of user
questions = 0 #number of questions asked
operator = ["+","-","*"]
number1 = random.randint(1,20)
number2 = random.randint(1,20)
print("You have now reached the next level!This is a test of your addition and subtraction")
print("You will now be asked ten random questions")
while questions<10: #while I have asked less than ten questions
    operator = random.choice(operator)
    question = '{} {} {}'.format(number1, operator, number2)
    print("What is " + str(number1) +str(operator) +str(number2), "?")
    answer = input()
    if answer ==(number1,operator,number2): 
        print("You are correct")
        score =score+1
    else:
        print("incorrect")
```

Sorry if I have been unclear, thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Use functions in a dictionary:

```
operator_functions = {
    '+': lambda a, b: a + b, 
    '-': lambda a, b: a - b,
    '*': lambda a, b: a * b, 
    '/': lambda a, b: a / b,
}
```

Now you can map an operator in a string to a function:

```
operator_functions[operator](number1, number2)
```

There are even ready-made functions for this is the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html):

```
import operator

operator_functions = {
    '+': operator.add, 
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.truediv,
}
```

Note that you need to be *careful* about using variable names! You used `operator` first to create a list of operators, then also use it to store the one operator you picked with `random.choice()`, *replacing* the list:

```
operator = random.choice(operator)
```

Use *separate names* here:

```
operators = ["+","-","*"]

# ...

picked_operator = random.choice(operators)
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I am very new to Python, you lost me at dictionary, is there any way I could do it using roughly the same as my existing code? Thanks though

Comment: @Alex: You *could* use `if operator == '+': result = number1 + number2`, `elif operator == '-':`, etc. But that is not nearly as efficient.

Comment: @Alex: Either approach runs a different piece of code based on your `operator` value, but the dictionary is simply.. more efficient and compact. See the [tutorial on dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) lib, creating  a dict with operators as keys and the methods as values.

```
from operator import add, mul, sub
import random

score = 0  # score of user
questions = 0  # number of questions asked
operators = {"+": add, "-": sub, "*": mul}
print("You have now reached the next level!This is a test of your addition and subtraction")
print("You will now be asked ten random questions")
# create list of dict keys to pass to random.choice
keys = list(operators)
# use range 
for _ in range(10):  
    number1 = random.randint(1, 20)
    number2 = random.randint(1, 20)
    operator = random.choice(keys)
    # cast answer to int, operators[operator]will be either add, mul or sub
    # which we then call on number1 and number2
    answer = int(input("What is {} {} {}?".format(number1,operator, number2)))
    if answer == (operators[operator](number1, number2)):
        print("You are correct")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("incorrect")
```

You  need to cast `answer` to int a string could never be equal to an int.
In the code  `random.choice(keys)` will pick one of the three dicts keys `* - or +`, we do a lookup on the dict with `operators[operator]` i.e `operators["*"]` returns `mul` we can then call `mul(n1,n2)`  on the two random numbers.

You also need to move the  `number1 = random.randint(1, 20)`.. inside the while loop or you will end up asking the same questions and you can pass the string to input, you don't need to print.

Comment: Thankyou! Just tried it and this works.  Coukd you possibly explain how it works though - what does the random.choice(keys) line allow?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) function.  `eval` will take a string with math operators and compute the answer. In your final if statement check it like this...

```
if answer == eval(question):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator
import random
operators = {
    "+": operator.add,
    "-": operator.sub,
    "/": operator.truediv,
    "*": operator.mul
}


y = float(input("Enter number: "))
z = float(input("Enter number: "))
x = random.choice(operators.keys())

print (operators[x](y, z))
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, instead of making the dictionary, I would just create a list of tuples with the operator string representation and the operator builtin function:

```
import operator
import random

operators = [('+', operator.add), ('-', operator.sub), ('*', operator.mul)]

for i in range(10):
    a = random.randint(1, 20)
    b = random.randint(1, 20)
    op, fn = random.choice(operators)
    print("{} {} {} = {}".format(a, op, b, fn(a, b)))
```

---

```
14 * 4 = 56
6 + 12 = 18
11 + 11 = 22
7 - 9 = -2
9 - 4 = 5
17 * 5 = 85
19 - 13 = 6
9 - 4 = 5
20 * 20 = 400
5 * 3 = 15
```

---

`Random.choice` on your list will return a tuple that you can unpack into the operator str representation and the function that you can call.

```
import operator
import random

score = 0
operators = [('+', operator.add), ('-', operator.sub), ('*', operator.mul)]

for i in range(10):
    a = random.randint(1, 20)
    b = random.randint(1, 20)
    op, fn = random.choice(operators)
    prompt = "What is {} {} {}?\n".format(a, op, b)
    if int(input(prompt)) == fn(a, b):
        score += 1
        print("You are correct")
    else:
        print("incorrect")

print("Score: {}".format(score))
```